# Enable CORS from front-end in React with axios?

Tags: reactjs, cors, axios

I am using React on the front-end and I'm calling API from another domain which I don't own. My axios request:

```
axios(requestURL, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': key,
            withCredentials: true,
            mode: 'no-cors',
          }
```

I keep on getting the same error: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing. Is this something I can overcome from the frontend? I know for a fact that people use that API so it can't be backend fault, right? I tried requesting a lot of APIs and not even one worked with my code. I tried using https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com and it worked fine for like a week, I think its down today. I want my site to stay 24/7 so using a proxy is not an option

Comment: What API are you trying to hit? Normally you get a key/token.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will, unfortunately, need to proxy the request somehow. CORS requests will be blocked by the browser for security reasons. To avoid this, backend needs to inject allow origin header for you.

Solutions depend on where you need to proxy, dev or production.

**Development environment or node.js production webserver**

The easiest way to do it in this scenario is to use the *'http-proxy-middleware'* npm package

```
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function (app) {
    app.use(proxy('/api', {
        target: 'http://www.api.com',
        logLevel: 'debug',
        changeOrigin: true
    }));
};
```

**Production - Web server where you have full access**
Check the following page to see how to enable such proxying on your webserver:

https://enable-cors.org/server.html

**Production - Static hosting / Web server without full access**

*If your hosting supports PHP*, you can add a php script like: https://github.com/softius/php-cross-domain-proxy

Then hit a request from your app to the script, which will forward it and inject headers on the response

*If your hosting doesn't support PHP*
Unfortunately, you will need to rely on a solution like the one that you have used.

In order to avoid relying on a third party service, you should deploy a proxy script somewhere that you will use.

My suggestions are:

- Move to a hosting that supports php :) (Netlify could be a solution, but I'm not sure)
- You can deploy a node.js based proxy script of your own to Firebase for example (firebase functions), to ensure it will not magically go down, and the free plan could possibly handle your amount of requests.
- Create a free Amazon AWS account, where you will get the smallest instance for free for a year, and run an ubuntu server with nginx proxy there.

Comment: Hello, what is 'app'?

Comment: @Psymon25 Not really sure what you mean. This is not a react or javascript-specific issue but is generally tied to browser security settings for CORS in Chromium-based browsers.

Comment: @VlatkoVlahek i removed as i was somewhat frustrated and only experienced this in react testing, since this i learned differently so apologies and thanks for your input.

Comment: @Psymon25 No problem. I've previously had a lot of frustrations with this topic as well so I understand :)

Answer (score 2):

You should allow CORS from back-end for making requests.

Comment: So if I'm not the owner of the backend and I dont have any contact with him there is nothing I can do?

Comment: @IdleSolution You can set up a server of your own that has CORS enabled that is a proxy for the real backend.

Comment: yes, you are right. It is impossible to allow cors from front-end

Answer (score 1):

One can use [CORS-anywhere](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere). It is a NodeJS reverse proxy which adds CORS headers to the proxied request.

If I want to add CORS to **https://test-example.com**, then I'd just do it as follows:

```
https://cors-anywhere-herokuapp.com/https://test-example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

While using Chrome one can use CORS extension. Eg. [MOESIF CORS plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/moesif-origin-cors-change)

You would be able to bypass the CORS issue using such plugins, at least while using chrome.