# Axios post request in React JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, http, axios

Im on a React JS project and i need to request some data from a server.I want to obtain this information before the render , because i want to show the data on the browser the first time is charged.

This is the code i have written (Before the render() of a Component):

```
componentDidMount(){
        axios.post('https://XXX',{
            msisdn:"XXXX",
            passwd:"XXXX"
        }).then(res=>console.log(res.data))
    }
```

But I obtain the following errors:
[Errors obtained after the axios request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAMo0.png)

My questions are:

- How can I solve this problems without modifying the CORS conf on the server?.

I have my react project on a server and i was thinking about if it would be possible to make the request from the server and then send the data or obtaine it from React.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I feel you don't have (Read/ write) access  permission to your url

Comment: You can't do anything about the `CORS` errors in the browsers. Like you said, you'd have to modify the `CORS` headers on the server. You could, however, create your own server/proxy that's going to call that API for you and then you can just expose an `API` endpoint that's just going to return the server's response back to your client application. Don't forget to set appropriate `CORS` headers for your own server, otherwise you will be running into the same issues.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enable CORS from front-end in React with axios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55200786/enable-cors-from-front-end-in-react-with-axios)